# Tengo que crear este menu en java y C#, pero recien estoy aprendiendo arreglos unidimensionales y no se como sumar las matrices porque me da error

Tags: java, array

Esta es la orden del ejercicio: Realizar una aplicación con el siguiente menú:

1. Llenar el arreglo A de manera aleatoria.
2. Llenar el arreglo B de manera aleatoria.
3. Realizar C = A + B
4. Realizar C = B - A
5. Mostrar Arreglo (Permitiendo al usuario elegir entre el arreglo A, B, o C).
6. Salir.
   **Nota.**
   El rango de los números aleatorios para los arreglos será de [-100 a 100]. Validar que
   se pueda realizar opción 3, 4 y mostrar el arreglo C.
   La longitud de los arreglos es la misma, por lo tanto, solo se solicitará una vez.

La opcion 1 y 2 si pude pero el resto no porque no se como se suman me da error, ayuda.

Porfavor si me ayudan haciendo con mi mismo codigo gracias sino cuando utilizan case y otros metodos no entiendo aun.

```
public static void Menu (int tamaño)
    {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            int opcion1 = 1;
            int opcion2 = 2;
            int opcion3 = 3;
            int opcion4 = 4;
            int opcion5 = 5;
            
            //menu
            
            System.out.println(" Bienvenido al menu de opciones ");
            System.out.println(" Arreglo Aleatorio A: 1");
            System.out.println(" Arreglo Aleatorio B: 2");
            System.out.println(" Arreglo C = A+B: 3");
            System.out.println(" Arreglo C = B-A: 4");
            System.out.println(" Mostrar Arreglo A-B-C: 5");
            System.out.println(" Salir ");
            
            //ingreso opciones por teclado
            
            System.out.println("Ingrese la opción que desea realizar");
            
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            
            //OPCION 1
            if (opcion == opcion1)
            {
                int A [] = new int [tamaño];
                
                System.out.print(" A =  [ " );
                for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) 
                {
                     
                     A[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                     System.out.print(A[j] +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
               
            }
            
            //OPCION 2
            
            if (opcion == opcion2)
            {
                int B [] = new int [tamaño];
                
                System.out.print(" B =  [ " );
                for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) 
                {
                     
                     B[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                     System.out.print(B[j] +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
               
            }
            
            //OPCION3
            
            if (opcion == opcion3)
            {
                int A [] = new int [tamaño];
                
                System.out.print(" A =  [ " );
                for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) 
                {
                     A[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                     System.out.print(A[j] +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
                
                int B [] = new int [tamaño];
                
                System.out.print(" B =  [ " );
                for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) 
                {
                     B[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                     System.out.print(B[j] +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
                
                //SUMA
                 int C [] = new int [tamaño];
                 C= A[i]+B[i];
                 System.out.println(C[i]);
            }

          if (opcion == opcion4)
            {
                int A [] = new int [tamaño];
                
                System.out.print(" A =  [ " );
                for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) 
                {
                     A[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                     System.out.print(A[j] +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
                
                int B [] = new int [tamaño];
                
                System.out.print(" B =  [ " );
                for (int j = 0; j < tamaño; j++) 
                {
                     B[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
                     System.out.print(B[j] +"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("]");
                
                //RESTA
                 int C [] = new int [tamaño];
                 C= B[i]-A[i];
                 System.out.println(C[i]);
            }

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        Menu(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que quieres sumar los arreglos no es válida en `Java`. Debes hacerlo de forma similar a como hiciste la iteración para llenar las matrices `A` y `B`. Por ejemplo para tu suma.

```
//SUMA
int C[] = new int [tamanio];

for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; ++i)
  C[i] = A[i] + B[i];

System.out.print("C =  [ " );
for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; ++i)
  System.out.print(C[i] + "  ");
System.out.println("]");
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Comment: ese error me da y el 3 es por el lenght porque en tamaño en el main le puse 3 pero al ejecutar la forma que me dio usted para calcular la suma me da error, le intente corregir poniendo en los for el C.lenght o A.length y me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje, podria ayudarme porfavor

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar el código actualizado con la sugerencia que añadiste?

Comment: ya le corregi muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: ¿Cuál era el problema?